# Load a file into an array, and separate it twice with two delimiters

Tags: python, arrays, delimiter

I would like to import a file and then use two delimiters to load them into two arrays. I would like to open data.txt which contains:

```
place1,time1
place2,time2
place3,time3
```

...

I would like array `places` to be the places before , and `times` to be the times after the ','

I can successfully load the files with open() and then split them into an array with `line.strip().split('\n')`

```py
data = open("data.txt", "r")
infoArray = []
for line in data:
    infoArray.append(line.strip().split('\n'))
data.close()

print infoArray
```

I would expect places[0] to be place1, places[1] to be place2, etc... And for time[0] to be time1, time[1], to be time2, and so-forth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/csv.html) module for reading comma-delimited data, as well as `zip()` while unpacking the iterable `reader` object:

```
>>> import csv
>>> with open("data.txt") as f:
...     reader = csv.reader(f)
...     p, t = zip(*reader)
... 
>>> p
('place1', 'place2', 'place3')
>>> t
('time1', 'time2', 'time3')
```

The argument for using `csv` over trying to parse the file yourself is that it will deal with things such as quoted values (in standard CSV format) that a call to `str.split(line, ',')` would fail with.

Whether you are using just a `file` object or a `csv.reader` result, either of these are iterable; when you iterate over them, you get the individual lines of the file.  Here's an example on a more visible input, where you can visualize `[1, 2]` as corresponding to the first row of data and `[3, 4]` as the second:

```
>>> a, b = zip(*[[1, 2], [3, 4]])
>>> a
(1, 3)
>>> b
(2, 4)
```

Lastly, this example uses `with open()`, creates a context manager and [ensures that the file is closed](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects) when you're done using it.